# How do you store countable properties of django models?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-models, nosql

I have a database representing linked entities. There are some "expensive" operations on this entities - countable properties. I want to store this countable properties neither as a  field in database nor as some cached value:

> cache.set(full_entityname_entity_id, property_value)

doesn't seems beautiful and I also can provide "expire" method on the counted property.
Maybe, it's time to use redis or other nosql solutions for this purpose, maybe, I don't know all the advantages of Postgresql, python and django. I think, this is a common problem: what is the better way to solve it?

Comment: Why don't you want to store it in a cache?

Comment: Expiring event doesn't depend on time, it depends on changes in db. So the same property of different objects can be actual for 10 minutes or for days. I think, cache is built for other purpose...

Comment: You can update the cache based on a trigger in your db that fires when the fields that are part of the calculation are updated.

Comment: Trigger will fire in Postgresql. Do you talk about Postgresql  additional field? Of course, I can delete values from cache on appropriate save() method in models that influence to that property. So, as I understand, the best methood is cache.set('key', 0) and cache.delete('key').

Comment: In addition to the previous comment of Burhan Khalid: you can override `save` method or use django signals to update your cache (in this method you check cache expire condition and if cache need update you just do it). You don't need to use db triggers.